# Drawing specific lines in html

Tags: html, css, image

I'm putting design into html+css - the question is - how do i draw curved lines on the sides, so that it would be scalable and responsive? What's the best way to do it
[image]

Comment: Can you post your related code?

Comment: Are you speaking about white borders with rounded corners?

Comment: yes, the borders with rounded conners on both sides

Comment: The image you're showing would be easiest created in an image editing program and just shown on your website, however I do have a way of generating the same effect in mind, if you really want that

Comment: I do want to generate that effect. 
I know how to just pate image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check as per the description this answer get your perfectly needs.

```css
body {
    background:#007DAD;
}
section {
    text-align: center;
}
h1.one {
    position: relative;
    margin-top: 0;
}
h1.one:before {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    border: solid 1px #FFF;
    width: 100%;
    height: 150px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    z-index: 1;
    border-radius:5px;
}
h1.one span {
    background: #007DAD;
    padding: 0 20px;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 5;
}
.row {
    height: 100px;
 margin: 10px;
}
.circle {
    border:4px solid red;
 height: 70px;
 width: 70px;
 border-radius: 40px;
    margin:10px auto;
    display:inline-block;
}
button {
    padding:10px;
    background-color: gray; 
    color:white;
    border: 2px solid;
    border-radius: 5px;
    margin-top:-10px;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 5;
}
```

```html
<section>
    <h1 class="one">
        <span>It Has Naver Been Easier</span>
    </h1>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="circle"><p>1</p></div>
        <div class="circle"><p>2</p></div>
        <div class="circle"><p>3</p></div>
    </div>
    <button type="button">Order Now</button>
</section>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can try this one:

```
section{
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 600px;
  text-align: center;
}
  h1 {
    position: relative;
//margin-top: 20px;
  }

  h1.one {
    margin-top: 0;
  }

  h1.one:before {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    border: solid 1px black;
    width: 100%;
    height: 150px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    z-index: 1;
      border-radius:5px;
  }

  h1.one span {
    background: #fff;
    padding: 0 20px;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 5;
  }

/* method 2*/

button
{
  padding:8px;
  background-color: gray
  color:white;
  border: 2px solid;
    border-radius: 15px;
  margin-top:2px;
  position: relative;
    z-index: 5;

}
.circle
{
    border:4px solid red;
    height: 70px;
    width: 70px;
    border-radius: 40px;
   position:relative;
    margin:10px auto;
   display:inline-block;
}

.row
{

    height: 100px;
    width: 700px;
    margin: 10px;
    text-align:center;
    position:relative;
}
```

[DEMO FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ivinraj/xeps69x7/3/)